# Angular NgRoute and leaflet declaration directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm pretty new to Angular, and I'm trying to make a little app for learning.

I use the leaflet directive and want to add the `NgRoute` directive too but I have some errors in the console.

Here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive'], ['ngRoute']);
app.controller("toulouseController", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    osloCenter: {},
    markers: {},
    defaults: {
      scrollWheelZoom: false
    }
  });
```

I don't know if I can't declare two directive at the same time...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive', 'ngRoute']);`
That should work.

Answer (score 2):

As per AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module), the syntax of angular.module is

```
angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);
```

So you should use

```
angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive','ngRoute']);
                                 /\
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                 ||
                   All dependencies should be specified in single array.
```